# difference between (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int)) and int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*n)

Tags: c, arrays, heap-memory

I'm doing an exercise where I'm allocating my array data to the heap instead of the stack.

so I changed my code from:

`int array[n];`

to

`int *array = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));`

When I'm looking at my friends code that got the same exercise, they wrote `int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);`

so,
what is the difference between `int *array = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));` and `int *array = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);` ?

Comment: Theirs is good without the cast, and some would prefer it like this: `int *array = malloc(n * sizeof *array);`

Comment: okey so its the same thing and both is working?
is it like in math that 10/4 is the same as 5/2 ?

Comment: Have you read the linked question?

Comment: Better to use `int *array = malloc(sizeof *array * n);` and avoid trying to get and maintain the right type.